# Getting X-Y coordinates for visio shapes using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, visio

I have recently started using vb.net for programming.
I am trying to get the X-Y coordinates of all the shapes in visio into a csv file.
I found a VBA code by Russell Christopher in which the code does exactly what I need, but it is in VBA. I tried rewriting the code in VB.net but as I am new, I do not know all of the syntax. Can anyone here please help me on that. 
Here is the code that I need to convert.

```
Public Sub WriteTableauPointsFile()
Dim oShape As Visio.Shape
Dim oPath As Visio.Path
Dim oPoints() As Double

'Set the output file to be the same as the source file, but .CSV
oFileName = Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, Len(ActiveDocument.FullName) - 3) & "csv"

'Set the separator character
oSeparator = "|"

'If file already exists, delete it
If Dir(oFileName) <> "" Then
    Kill oFileName
End If

'Open the output file and write the header line
oFile = FreeFile
Open oFileName For Append As #oFile
Print #oFile, "ShapeNo" & oSeparator & "ShapeName" & oSeparator & "PathNo" & oSeparator & "PointNo" & oSeparator & "X" & oSeparator & "Y"

'Get all the shapes on the page
ActiveWindow.SelectAll
Set oShapes = ActiveWindow.Selection


'Cycle through the shapes
For Each oShape In oShapes

    'Shapes can have multiple paths
    For j = 1 To oShape.Paths.Count
        Set oPath = oShape.Paths(j)

        'Enumerate the points in each path with 0.5 sensitivity for curves
        oPath.Points 0.5, oPoints
        i = 0
        Do While i < UBound(oPoints)
            x = Int(oPoints(i))
            y = Int(oPoints(i + 1))
            i = i + 2

            'Write the record for each point
            Print #oFile, oShape.Index; oSeparator; oShape.Text; oSeparator; j; oSeparator; i; oSeparator; x; oSeparator; y
        Loop
    Next j
Next

'Close the file and exit
Close #oFile
```

End Sub

Based on trial and error I understood that there is no such thing as "open" in vb.net. I was able to successfully convert until the "open" statement starts.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
- Miki

Comment: Ok so far I have converted everything except this:
`oPath.Points 0.5, oPoints
        i = 0
        Do While i < UBound(oPoints)
            x = Int(oPoints(i))
            y = Int(oPoints(i + 1))
            i = i + 2
`
It gives an error and I am not able to convert it. Any help on this please?

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. Thought I would post it here so that it might be helpful someone looking for similar thing in future.

```
Dim oPoints() as Double
oPath.Points(0.5, oPoints)
    i = 0
    Do While i < UBound(oPoints)
        x = Int(oPoints(i))
        y = Int(oPoints(i + 1))
        i = i + 2
```

Remaining portion of the code remains the same.